# Q: Trigonometry Bearings: Find distance between 2 points based on separate bearings

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Just finished a trig exam with the following problem and most everyone in the class arrived at a very different answer than me. The Professor and most of the class determined that to solve for side AB you would simply use the law of sines:

[image: Problem Diagram]

**Problem:**
A land developer wants to find the distance across a small lake in the middle of his proposed development. The bearing from A to B is N15°W. The developer leaves point A and travels 66 yards perpendicular to AB to point C. The bearing from C to point B is N75°W. Determine the distance, AB, across the small lake. Round distance to nearest yard.

**Class Solution:**
(using law of sines)
**step1:** 66 yards / sin15° = AB / sin75°
**step2:** (66)(sin75°) / sin15° = AB
**step3:** 246.32 ≈ AB

My Confusion with this is that the angles are not directly stated in the problem, at least from my understanding of trig bearings. It seems like the Professor and the students assumed that (angle B = 15°) and since (angle A = 90°) then (angle C = 75°).

So I created a little diagram using actual measured angles to figure out what the triangle looked like based on my understanding of bearings (for N15°W = start at North or 90° on a unit circle and move counter clockwise 15°) and from my diagram I determined that (angle C = 30°), (angle A = 90°), therefore (angle B = 60°). I ran through this problem multiple times and even looked at similar problems both in the book and online, and basically want to validate which answer is correct. Thanks for playing!

**My solution:**
(Using law of sines)
**step1:** 66 yards / sin60° = AB / sin30°
**step2:** (66)(sin30°) / sin60° = AB
**step3:** 38.11 ≈ AB

Comment: What not just $AB = 66 \tan 30^0$.

Comment: True, based on my solution, AB = (66)(tan30°), I guess my real question is how everyone else in the class derived the angles based on the bearings. Is (∠C = 30°) or (∠C = 75°)

Comment: If the notation for the bearings is that [used by the US Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_(navigation)#US_Army_definition) then your answer is correct.

Comment: 1) The correct wording of the bold-faced is "The bearing **of** B from A is $N 15^0 W$". 2) The simplest thing to do is to ask your professor or your classmates to draw their figures. Then, we can verify which version is correct.

Comment: Here is what one of my classmates sent me as an explanation of what they thought were the values of the triangle. Good times. [classmate example](http://creativecrux.s3.amazonaws.com/images/math-example/trig-problem-classmate.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I’m going to add a couple of points to your diagram for clarity:

[image]

Since $\angle{BAC}$ and $\angle{EAD}$ are both right angles, then $\angle{EAB}=\angle{DAC}$. The lines $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{EC}$ are parallel, so $\angle{EAC}=\angle{DAC}=15°$. Finally, $\overline{EC}\perp\overline{DC}$, so $\angle{ECB}=90°-75°=15°$.

Comment: Do you mean  $\angle ECA = \angle DAC = 15^\circ$ in the second to last sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Your classmate (who wrote the figures linked in a comment) was correct that
$75 - 15 = 60.$ That's why angle $\angle ABC$, **not** angle $\angle ACB,$
is equal to $60$ degrees.
It follows that $\angle ACB = 30^\circ.$
One need only draw a scale diagram on graph paper with a ruler and protractor
(something your classmates **and** your instructor apparently could use some practice with)
to confirm these fact,
or one could simply chase angles around the figure and determine the angles correctly by arithmetic.

The angles in the equation
$$
\frac{66}{\sin 15^\circ} = \frac{AB}{\sin75^\circ}
$$
appear to be derived from the standard trigonometry technique learned by many students,
"Oh look, there's a number in the problem statement, it must plug directly into a formula I memorized by rote, let's put it in the 'nearest' place I can find."

What is a bit shocking is that the instructor fell into the same schoolchild error. It is even more shocking if the figure in the question is (as it appears to be) the actual figure that was presented as an illustration of the problem in the original exam materials.

Your solution is completely correct: the correct angle measurements and the correct application of the law of sines.